Purchase a product under Stripe connected account
How to purchase a product created under a stripe connected account, using API
I created a product in a stripe connected account, and I tried to purchase it, I followed stripe checkout session creation flow in the documentation, but unabele to make a payment,
server logic
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY as string, {
  apiVersion: "2024-04-10",
  typescript: true,
});

export async function POST(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  const { data } = await req.json();
  const { price } = data;
  console.log(price);

  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(
      {
        mode: "payment",
        line_items: [
          {
            price,
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],

        ui_mode: "embedded",
        return_url:
          "http://localhost:3000/pages/checkout/return?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
      },
      {
        stripeAccount: "acct_**************",
      }
    );

    console.log(session);
    return NextResponse.json({ session });
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}


front end (nextJS)
"use client";
import * as React from "react";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import {
  EmbeddedCheckoutProvider,
  EmbeddedCheckout,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY as string
);
const Checkout = () => {
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchClientSecret = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post("/api/stripe-checkout", {
          data: {
            price: "price_**************", // price id from connected account
          },
        });
        setClientSecret(response.data.session.client_secret);
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch client secret");
      }
    };

    fetchClientSecret();
  }, []);
  console.log(clientSecret);

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "white", height: "100vh" }}>
      {clientSecret && (
        <EmbeddedCheckoutProvider
          stripe={stripePromise}
          options={{ clientSecret }}
        >
          <EmbeddedCheckout />
        </EmbeddedCheckoutProvider>
      )}`your text`
    </div>
  );
};

export default Checkout;

but this didnt work for me

Could you please share more details about the issue here? what is not working exactly ?

used stripe hosted page option and it was resolved the problem
BE -


 await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(
      {
        mode: "payment",
        line_items: [
          {
            price: "price_**************",
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],

        success_url: "http://localhost:3000/pages/success",
        cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000",
      },
      {
        stripeAccount: "acct_*********",
      }
    );



FE -


await axios.post("/api/stripe-checkout", {
        data: {
          price: "price_************", 
        },
      });
      const session = response.data.session;
      window.location.href = session.url;



